# json stringify, encode and decode - why?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

i have some questions that I want to ask, I building a web site and I send in ajax data and do decode and decode (js to php).

1) I want to ask why we should use in ajax encode and decode on json ?

2) what the json stringify do?  I do it like this:

```
var data = JSON.stringify([category, amount, repeated, note]);
```

but I not realy understand why I should use this..my freind told me its not secure to send ajax without json encode, is it true?

Comment: Json is a common ground among language when it comes to passing information around. JSON.stringify is the equivalent as PHPs json_encode(). It really has little to do with security as it does communication between languages or a client and a server.

Comment: Please put one question per... question. Have you googled these questions? There are a number of sites around that explain all this. You need to do a basic amount of research before asking questions on SO. SO is also not for opinion based questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, AJAX is not tied to [JSON](http://json.org/) but is the most used. You could use XML, yaml or you own format. On other hand, you always have sanitize and validate any data sent by the user. This is the real security risk.

Second, if you use a library as jQuery or AngularJs, you do not need `stringify` a javascript object (it is not the same as a JSON) the library does this for you.

```
// jQuery example
$.ajax({
    url: '/save.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        id: 5,
        name: 'pollin14'
    }
};
```

---

```
// Save.php
$id   = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Lastly, `stringily` transforms a javascript object to a javascript string. It is useful if you want to save a javascript object in a cookie, for example. Because a cookie only can save strings. Then when you retrieve the cookie you can use `JSON.parse` to get a javascript object.